# Component rendered twice are sharing states and they shouldn't share them

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

The **problem** is that **two views (same component) load same info** (each one is a furnace, `MainFurnaceView`), an they should be loading different one. **At first render** (it can be seen for some miliseconds) **they render different info**, so it's okay, but later both views are showing the same info, after a second unwanted render. I think they're sharing the states between them.

I've got a `MainFurnaceView` element rendered twice in the `MainScreen`, the only property I give to it is `furnace`, on the first view, `furnace={'forge'}`, on the second one `furnace={'preheat'}`. Because of this property they should be loading different info.

On the `MainFurnaceView`, it logs the furnace prop **correctly** in the constructor, and **also takes well info** from `AsyncStorage` (called on constructor also). On render, **at first, each view logs info of the wanted furnace, but later it loads and logs info of the 2nd furnace on both views**.

Code:
`MainScreen`

```
<MainFurnaceView
 //Tried with and without both onRef 
 //onRef={(ref) => (this.Option = ref)}              
 furnace={"forge"}/>
<MainFurnaceView
 //onRef={(ref) => (this.Option = ref)}
 furnace={"preheat"}/>
```

`MainFurnaceView`

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

console.log('Constructor:', this.props.furnace);//Logs well
this.state = {
  //Pieces to use at furnace view, tried with Object.assign and directly without it
  furnacePieces:
    this.props.furnace === "forge"
      ? Object.assign(pieces.forge, {})
      : Object.assign(pieces.preheat, {}),
};
this.getData()/*Call to AsyncStorage here*/;}

getData = async () => {
//Get data (data) from key and save it as state
try {
  let furnace;
  if (this.props.furnace === "forge")
    furnace = await AsyncStorage.getItem(consts.KEY_FORGE_DIMENSIONS);
  else furnace = await AsyncStorage.getItem(consts.KEY_PREHEAT_DIMENSIONS);

  furnace = JSON.parse(furnace);
  console.log("getData: ", this.props.furnace, furnace);
  if (typeof furnace[0].r === "number") {
    this.setState({
      furnaceRows: furnace[0].r,
      furnaceCols: furnace[0].c,
      furnaceHeights: furnace[0].h,
    });
  } else {
    console.warn("not found");
    this.setState({
      furnaceRows: 3,
      furnaceCols: 3,
      furnaceHeights: 1,
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  // error reading value
  console.log(e);
}
```

};

I call `console.log('Render: ', this.props.furnace)` on the render and there I also log the property furnace.

Log:

```
Constructor: forge
Render:  forge
Constructor: preheat
Render:  preheat
getData: forge Array [
  Object {
    "c": 4,
    "h": 1,
    "r": 6,
  },
]
Render:  preheat
getData: preheat Array [
  Object {
    "c": 4,
    "h": 1,
    "r": 4,
  },
]
Render:  preheat
```

**What I understand with this log** is that the first view is created and rendered, and then the second view is created and rendered, but later both reload with the property furnace as 'preheat' instead of one with 'forge' and the other with 'preheat'.

**UPDATE:**
If I don't call `getData` on constructor, views aren't re-rendered, so the info for each furnace is taken well. The problem now is that I need to get those dimensions from `AsyncStorage`, and idk how to do it without, as getting that info makes a new render and the prop furnace is changed.
**BUT**
If I make anything to re-render the `mainScreen` with both `mainFurnaceView`'s (for example open another modal and close it) it renders on both views the 'preheat' info.

Comment: The problem is most likely this: `this.getData()`; I would expect that call to receive the type of furnace as param, otherwise it'll return the same data for both views, I guess? Or is that method using the prop? Anyway, the problem is in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: The type of furnace is received as prop, `getData` is just to receive the dimensions of each furnace from `AsyncStorage`, as seen on the updated log, the dimensions are taken well from `AsyncStorage` (I think they're logged late because of being async). I updated also the question with the `getData` function. Thx

Comment: I don't think we can debug this without a [mre]. Both components' `furnace` prop is hardcoded to be different; I don't see anything that causes the first one to render as the other.

Comment: First of all, **don't load data in the constructor**. You'll run into race conditions when you try to `setState` before the component is mounted. Instead, load data in `componentDidMount`. Second, you haven't showed where you defined `pieces`. Since you then use `Object.assign`, the original object gets changed, which might cause unexpected consequences.

Comment: Pieces is just a constant taken from a file called pieces.js and imported at `MainFurnaceView`. About the reproducible example, I'll try to do it, but rn I'm too busy. Thx for the help.